# Android retrofit 401 after successful login / register

Tags: java, php, android, laravel, api

After I Login / Register in my app, I try to call a get route, which shall get me some data, but if I click on the button I do get a

> onResponse: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401,
>   message=Unauthorized,
>   url=http://192.168.3.15/myApp/public/api/getImage}

my call Looks like this:

```
    ApiService service;
    TokenManager tokenManager;
    Call<ImageResponse> call;
    ....

    tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
    service = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManager);

     ....

    @OnClick(R.id.testImageButton)
    void getImages() {
        call = service.getStreamBase64();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ImageResponse> call, Response<ImageResponse> response) {
                Log.w(CLASS_LABEL, "onResponse: " + response );
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w(CLASS_LABEL, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage() );
            }
        });
    }
```

My Image Model:

```
public class Image {

    int id;
    String image;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

My Image Response:

```
public class ImageResponse {

    List<Image> data;

    public List<Image> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I did test the route on postman, which worked.

My api is built with laravel, the get route calls this method:

```
public function getImage()
{
    $data = DB::table('images')->first();
    return response()->json(['images' => $data ], 200, []);
}
```

The api route:

```
Route::get('image', ['as' => 'image', 'uses' => 'Api\ApiController@image']);
```

Comment: post the full get request here otherwise it's almost impossible to help you. Also, how is your API setup? jwt token? cookie? other?

Comment: there must be some difference between the request from postman and from your app, please show both

Comment: 401 response means that the request was successfully executed and the server returned that status code. This is not a problem with Retrofit, but in whatever authentication information you are including in the request that the server expects. If it works in Postman, then somehow you are misconfiguring Retrofit or not sending the same data.

Comment: ok I updated my question, comment if I missed anything which is important aswell

Comment: @Ali I updated the question, I do use OAuth2 (token)

Comment: In your OkHttpClient Builder set a new interceptor to log the OkHttp requests. (`HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY); okHttpBuilder..addInterceptor(logging)`)
Then check the logcat the see if your request contains the correct headers and everything (compare with your Postman request) as it seems that you're not correctly authenticate on your app.

Comment: `.setLevel` has been deprecated! Use `.level` instead!